# CSV array manipulation transpose in ms access vba

Tags: vba

I am working on this code already and I need help to transfer values from a csv in transposed form

---

```
Sub ImportCSV()

Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlWb1 As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWb2 As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim SourcePathAndName As Variant
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim SourceName As String
Dim NewNameAndPath As String

Const xlPasteValues As Long = -4163
Const xlCSV As Long = 6

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
SourcePathAndName = xlApp.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select source file...", , False)
If SourcePathAndName = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Aborting"
    GoTo Cleanup
End If

SourcePath = Left(SourcePathAndName, InStrRev(SourcePathAndName, "\"))
SourceName = Mid(SourcePathAndName, InStrRev(SourcePathAndName, "\") + 1)
NewNameAndPath = SourcePath & "Import-" & SourceName

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlWb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(SourcePathAndName)

xlWb1.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
Set xlWb2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
With xlWb2.Worksheets(1)

    .[a1:b1] = Array("Field", "Val")
    .[a2].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

End With

xlWb2.SaveAs NewNameAndPath, xlCSV
xlWb2.Close False
xlWb1.Close False

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ResponseImport", "tblQuestionResponses", NewNameAndPath, True
Kill NewNameAndPath

MsgBox "Done" 
Cleanup:
Set xlWb1 = Nothing
Set xlWb2 = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

My data is rows is

```
date | field1 | field2  | field3...|field 800

date |value   |value    |value ... |value
```

I was looking to change it to

```
date| Field1| value

date| Field2| value

date| field3| value
```

I was only able to read 1 row of the csv file and have the use the date as the grouping value, I have 2000+ rows and 800 columns. I also need not to include null values. Please help me manipulate the array. Thanks.

Comment: Please note MS Access has a 255 column limit on tables. Why not just copy your header row, transpose it, then copy value row and transpose that too, then import into Access? No need to pass through an array.

Comment: Yes i know of the limit, running it using excel vba I was able to read more than 255, actually 800 columns successfully read and transposed but in one row only using my code. Im trying to read the next rows up to 2000 while maintaining the field values on top as field flag. Doing a transpose in excel means I will do it 2000 times before I can import.

Comment: any idea anyone... please help... thanks

Comment: Split the problem in parts: 1) first be sure that the file is imported somewhere (an Excel file, for example). 2) create two arrays: one to hold the header and the other to hold each data row. 3) read the headers. 4) for each data row, read the row and write it in another place (sheet). Try to solve things in a simple way before complicating yourself.

Comment: thanks Barranka, yes i will try that with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looping through rows and transpose them.

```
Set xlWb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(SourcePathAndName)
Set xlWb2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    lastrow = xlWb1.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastcolum = xlWb1.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    ' ITERATES THROUGH 2,000 ROWS
    For i = 1 to lastrow
         ' COPIES ENTIRE ROW FROM COLUMNS 1 to 800
         With xlWb1.Worksheets(1)
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastcolumn)).Copy
         End With

         ' TRANSPOSES TO 2,000 COLUMNS <---- NOTE: TOO WIDE FOR MS ACCESS TABLE
         xlWb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Next i
```

Comment: hi parfait, it says Cells is an undefined Sub... how do I fix it? thanks

Comment: See edit. I forgot to declare the second workbook's first worksheet in paste line.

Comment: hi i parfait, i already included the changes you made, it still have the same error. Do I have to initialize anything? Thanks

Comment: hi parfait, it works fine however it only reads one line of data... it wont go to the next lines... i really appreciate all your help... thank you